# How normal maps work?

Tags: 3d, textures, normals

how can we guess 3d representation of a texture from a 2d texture?

The only data we know is RGB colors, and I don't see how we can deduce the height of something by its color.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: I am asking how do we obtain normal maps from textures, just like photoshop, gimp, etc does. I'd like to do it myself

Comment: You should edit the question to more align with your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Although the location offsets are 2D in a texture, each value is a 3D value. Instead of looking at the three values as RGB, why not look at them as XYZ? It says the direction and magnitude of a normal vector pointing in some direction in 3D space. Say a texture of 10x10 size would have 100 such normals, one jutting out of each offset (i, j). I hope that gives you enough for visualization.

**Tip:** Don't practise thinking textures as images, instead just consider them as LUTs (look-up tables) where values are just stored as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Normal maps are all about representing direction of surface normal, so it is a 3d vector, we are using RGB values of a texture pixel as XYZ components of a vector. (R for X , G for Y and B for Z). When shaders try to determine how surface responds to lights, they use this normal and tangent of surface to calculate light reflextion from surface. Here is how math is done:

```
textureColor = shaderTextures[0].Sample(SampleType, input.tex);

// Sample the pixel in the normal map.
bumpMap = shaderTextures[1].Sample(SampleType, input.tex);

// Expand the range of the normal value from (0, +1) to (-1, +1).
bumpMap = (bumpMap * 2.0) - 1.0;

// Calculate the normal from the data in the normal map.
bumpNormal = (bumpMap.x * input.tangent) + (bumpMap.y * input.binormal) + (bumpMap.z * input.normal);

// Normalize the resulting bump normal.
bumpNormal = normalize(bumpNormal);

// Invert the light direction for calculations.
lightDir = -lightDirection;

// Calculate the amount of light on this pixel based on the normal map value.
lightIntensity = saturate(dot(bumpNormal, lightDir));

// Determine the final diffuse color based on the diffuse color and the amount of light intensity.
color = saturate(diffuseColor * lightIntensity);

// Combine the final bump light color with the texture color.
color = color * textureColor;
```

Comment: I know that normal maps RGB represents vector XYZ. My question is how do we algorithmically obtain a normal map from a texture, like here : http://img359.imageshack.us/img359/4721/develpierrecopiejk7.jpg

Comment: @user2591935 We do not "obtain" a normal map from a texture, textures are raster images that can represent a normal map. I edited my answer by an example of some shader-like math code that uses a sample(raster image) as normal map in order to create bump effect on surface. I think it would help you understand what i mean.

Comment: Well you could obtain a normal map out of a series of images, or under extraordinary conditions. But not from any image.